# Rewrite in htaccess doesn't applying css with 2 parameters

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my htaccess content file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ([a-z]+)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ([a-z]+)/([1-9]+)$ astc/accueil.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

When I access to a page with one parameter like "localhost/assoc/accueil", I have no problem but for a page with 2 parameters like "localhost/assoc/accueil/2" The CSS isn't applying.

Any idea please ? Thanks.

Comment: how are you loading your css? start the path with a / or use a full http url then it should load at expected.

Comment: Oh thanks. When I use a full http it works. But I want if possible to do it by another way. I load it with the path " /assets/plugins/... " wich is in the website directory

Comment: since /assets/.... is not working looks like you'll need to use the full http you can create a variable that holds that address, then use that anywhere you need the links or any resource that way you only have to set it once.

Comment: Finally I will take that solution. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that because rules are evaluated from top to bottom, `localhost/assoc/accueil/2` will match the first rewrite rule so the last one never gets applied.

There are a few ways to fix it, but a simple way is:

1. reverse the order of your rules, so the more specific path occurs first
2. Replace `[L]` flags with `[END]`

> The CSS isn't applying.

I don't know what your problem has to do with CSS. Maybe I missed something

Comment: Sorry for the bad english. I mean CSS don't load. I replace [L] with [END] and it doen't work too. I reverse the order of the 2 rules too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I use @Dave's solution by using full http link.
Thanks to all of you.